# How to loop data imported from SQLite database

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express, ejs

I am building an **Express** app ,and i am using **SQLite** database, I managed to fetch the data from the database, but I want to display it in the interface ,So i did this :

**index.js**

```js
/* GET THE LIST OF HOMES*/
router.get('/:homes-list', (req,res) => {
  db.all( "SELECT * FROM home WHERE owner_id = ?",[
    req.user.id
  ],
  function(err, rows) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    
    const home = rows.map(function(row) {
      return {
        location: row.location,
        for: row.for,
      }
        
    });
    res.locals.homes = home; 
    console.log(res.locals.homes)
    res.redirect("/:homes-list", {home: res.locals.homes})
  });
});
```

Then I tried to display it for the user interface using **EJS:**

**index.ejs**

```html
                    <form action="/:homes-list" method="get">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                        <% home.forEach(function(homes) { %>
                            <tr>
                              <td><%= homes.location %></td>
                              <td><%= homes.for %></td> 
                            </tr>
                          <% }); %> 
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </form>
```

After i did all that i had an **error:**

**Error**

```
/media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/views/index.ejs:45 43| <table> 44| <tbody> >> 45| <% home.forEach(function(homes) { %> 46| <tr> 47| <td><%= homes.location %></td> 48| <td><%= homes.for %></td> home is not defined
ReferenceError: /media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/views/index.ejs:45
    43|                         <table>
    44|                             <tbody>
 >> 45|                         <% home.forEach(function(homes) { %>
    46|                             <tr>
    47|                               <td><%= homes.location %></td>
    48|                               <td><%= homes.for %></td> 

home is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (/media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:633:12), <anonymous>:11:8)
    at returnedFn (/media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:668:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:254:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:485:10)
    at View.render (/media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at /media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/routes/index.js:22:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

and i didn't understand the error, so i didn't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you mixed up variables, try this:

```
<% homes.forEach(function(home) { %>
   <tr>
       <td><%= home.location %></td>
       <td><%= home.for %></td> 
   </tr>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: it gave me this:

Comment: ```/media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/views/index.ejs:45 43| <table> 44| <tbody> >> 45| <% homes.forEach(function(home) { %> 46| <tr> 47| <td><%= home.location %></td> 48| <td><%= home.for %></td> homes is not defined
ReferenceError: /media/onour/Desing/Des/test/roshan/views/index.ejs:45
    43|       <table>
    44|        <tbody>
 >> 45|         <% homes.forEach(function(home) { %>
    46|          <tr>
    47|           <td><%= home.location %></td>
    48|           <td><%= home.for %></td> 

homes is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile ```

Comment: it's the same error